# Why won't these two functions convert decimals to binary (uint8_t)?

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have two functions which supposedly can convert decimals to binary, however I can't seem to get them to work if the decimal is above 3 (I get weird negative numbers). I can't fully understand the code in the functions as I've only just started to learn C, however I was hoping if someone could tell me if the functions work, or if I am just not doing something right i.e. should I be using int32_t type as the value to pass into the function?

```
uint8_t dec_to_bin(int decimal){
     int n = decimal, i, j, binno=0,dn;

     dn=n;
     i=1;

      for(j=n;j>0;j=j/2)
       {
        binno=binno+(n%2)*i;
        i=i*10;
        n=n/2;
       }

     return binno;
 }

uint8_t dec_to_bin2(int decimal){
    long long binaryNumber = 0;
    int remainder, i = 1;

    while (decimal!=0){
        remainder = decimal%2;
        decimal /= 2;
        binaryNumber += remainder*i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return binaryNumber;
}
```

Unfortunately I have no way to find out the values of the binary numbers as a uint_8 type as I am doing this on a micro-controller and there is no way to debug or print values anywhere (I have posted numerous threads asking how to do this, with no luck). We have however been provided with another function:

```
int bin_to_dec(uint64_t binary) {
    int result = 0;
    for ( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
        result = result * 10 + ((binary >> i) & 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This function converts the binary number back to an integer so I can display it on the screen with a library function (the library function can only display integers or strings). If I pass 10 into either of the decimal to binary converter functions, then pass the uint_8 value from either function to the binary to decimal converter and print to the LCD, I get -3110. This should just be 1010.

Comment: Your question is missing a test case: input, output and expected output.

Comment: Okay, will try fix now

Comment: You do know that *all* numbers are stored in binary? And that the different numbering systems (octal, hexadecimal, decimal *and* binary) are really just an issue for presentation of the values? So that means, it really makes no sense to convert an integer in decimal to an integer in binary, because it's really just the same number. If you want to *show* an integer (*any* integer) value as binary, then that's another thing altogether, and it's been well-asked about and have many duplicate here and all over the Internet.

Comment: `uint8_t` is only large enough to hold "binary" numbers up to 111 (i.e., seven). Perhaps `uint64_t` would be more suitable. Also, you can replace `for(j=n;j>0;j=j/2)` with `while (n)`.

Comment: Yes I thought that too. I changed them to uint64_t but am still getting the same values

Comment: "Binary" and "decimal" describe ways to convert numbers to and from strings of digits.  You don't have any strings of digits in that code, so you're just changing some number to some other number.  If that's really what you want, can you describe more exactly what you want the function to do, with examples?

Comment: I've tried your functions with uint8_t typedefed as signed char, unsigned char, and long long unsigned int, and they work as they should as far up as the number fits. Maybe you can show a complete program that exhibits the error.

Comment: `int` might be too small to hold the result too!

Comment: Your conversion is backwards too!

Comment: I think this might just have something to do with the micro-controller that I am using. Everyone else who has tried this has it working fine.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. All numbers are binary. Do you wish to convert to/from a binary _text string_ or what?

Comment: As long as the functions are declared as returning `uint8_t` they can't return an integer greater than 255.  It doesn't matter if you make e.g. `binaryNumber` inside of `dec_to_bin2` a bigger `long ling` value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but your `dec_to_bin` and `dec_to_bin2` functions are meaningless.  Throw them away.  They might -- *might* -- have a tiny bit of value as a teaching exercise.  But if you're trying to write actual code for a microcontroller to actually do something, you don't need these functions, and you don't want these functions.  (Also you need to understand *why* you don't need these functions.)

The problem is not that they're implemented wrongly.  They're fundamentally flawed in their very intent.

These functions seem to convert, for example, the integer 5 to the integer 101, and at first glance that might look like "decimal to binary conversion", but it's not.  You've just converted the number five to the number one hundred and one.

Let's look at this a different way.  If I say

```
int i = 17;
```

and if I then call

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

I see the value "17" printed, as I expect.  But I can also call

```
printf("%x\n", i);
```

and this prints `i`'s value in hexadecimal, so I see "11".  Did I just convert `i` from decimal to hexadecimal?  *No, I did not!*  I took the same number, "seventeen", and I printed it out in two different ways: in decimal, and in hexadecimal.

For all practical purposes, unless you're designing the actual hardware a program will run on, it really doesn't make sense to ask what base a number is stored in.  A variable like `int i` is just a number, an integer.  (Deep down inside, of course, on a conventional processor we know it's stored in binary all the time.)

The only time it makes sense to explicitly convert a number to binary is if you want to print it out in a human-readable text representation, in binary.  In that case, you're converting *from* an integer *to* a string.  (The string will consist of the characters `'0'` and `'1'`.)

So if you want to write a meaningful decimal-to-binary converter (which will actually be an anything-to-binary converter), either have it print the binary number out to the screen, or store it in a string (an array of characters, or `char []`).

And if you're in a class where you're being asked to write `uint8_t dec_to_bin(int decimal)` (or where your instructor is giving you examples of such functions), I can't help you, and I'm afraid you're doomed.  Half of what this instructor is teaching you is wrong or badly misleading, will seriously handicap you from ever being a successful C programmer.  Of course I can't tell you which half, because I don't know what other lies you're being taught.  Good luck -- you'll need it! -- unlearning these false facts later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're trying to store binary data as base 10 numbers instead of just printing or storing (as a `char[]`) the bits of an `int` (get `kth` bit of `n` as `(n >> k) & 1` then print/store), but I'll assume it's necessary.

Your solution could be prone to overflowing the `uint8_t` as mentioned in the comments. Even a `uint64_t` can only hold 19 bits of binary data in the format you're using, less than the 32 of typical ints. The return type of your second function is still `uint8_t`, this might just be a typo, but it means the internal representation of `long long` will be implicitly cast on return.

I've written some functions based on yours, but with a little more bit manipulation that work for me.

```
uint64_t dec_to_bin (int n)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    int k, i;
    // 64 bits can only hold 19 (log10(2^64)) bits in this format
    for (i = 0, k = n; k && i < 19; i++) {
        // Because the loop is limited to 19 we shouldn't need to worry about overflowing
        result *= 10;
        result += (n >> i) & 1;
        k /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}

int bin_to_dec (uint64_t n)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (n) {
        result <<= 1;
        result += n % 2;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tested your functions on the input `43` on my system and got

```
43        // Original Input
101011    // dec_to_bin2 with long long return type
10010011  // bin_to_dec
```

With an appropriately sized output, your `dec_to_bin2` function does work as expected.

And my functions:

```
43     // Original Input
110101 // dec_to_bin
43     // bin_to_dec
```

The endianness may not be what you're expecting, but that can be changed if necessary.